# CSS Animation on hover - fade out slowly when hover out

Tags: css, animation

I'm quite new to CSS Animations.
I've put together a simple effect whereby a link is hovered and a title appears and the opacity of a div on top of the image fades up.

This is all working and shown on this mockup:

http://tinyurl.com/l2rln4k

What I'm trying to do with no success is have the opacity div fade back down when the link area is exited (hover out). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so on your .overlay class make it always have a position: absolute and top: 0, left: 0; then add a transition to the background (i did .5s worked fine). The problem you have now is that when the anchor is not hovered the overlay is placed bellow it and not on top.

Tell me if that works